# Affordable, high quality mini guitar for all genres?

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar, classical-guitar

I'm looking for a high quality, affordable mini guitar without a cutout or a pickguard, that will be good for acoustic guitar genres as well as classical guitar genres.
What are some options?
Thanks!

Comment: I’m sorry to say this type of question does not get answered here. This link goes to a page that has the types of questions that will and won’t be answered on this site: https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic